# Validate user input in GWT?

Tags: java, validation, gwt

What is the best way to validate user input in GWT? Is there any built in support for input validation? or is there any external framework to do that ? taking into consideration that I'm using hibernate with GWT?

Thanks

Comment: I hope you're asking this question solely for user feedback.  Just a friendly reminder that all actual validation **must** be done server-side.  Client side checks so you can provide timely feedback to the user are nice, but they don't remove the need to check *everything* on the server as well.

Comment: @ Andrezej Doyle - Is it because Javascript can be disabled on client side?

Comment: @SidCool The user can modify any call sent to the server, that's why you should not rely on client side validation for keeping your data consistant and safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write static validation checker routines in a class stored in a "shared" package. Then, you can use that same code on the client and server side.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't gotten a good answer, I want to share my opinion with the validation frameworks that I have seen for GWT.

The thing with the frameworks is that they often try to accomplish two things:

- They want to be very general.
- They want to be non intrusive to your code.

This will sometimes succeed, but most of the time they don't. Writing such a framework has a cost, and that cost is you as a user of that framework that will pay.

Validation should, in my opinion be simple. Here is an example on how I solved validation using some code I put together:

```
    MasterValidator masterValidator = new MasterValidator();

    masterValidator.mandatory(messages.required_field(), lastnameBox, firstnameBox, genderBox);

    if (birthdateRequired) {
        masterValidator.mandatory(messages.required_field(), birthdateBox);
    }

    masterValidator.date(messages.date_format(), birthdateBox);

    masterValidator.email(messages.invalid_email(), emailBox);

    return masterValidator.validateStatus();
```

Here each of the input boxes inherit from my TextField (or some other input types) and these fields has an error label that will be set if the validation is unsuccessful.

I'm not saying that this is perfect, but it will get the job done simply. If you want to be inspired/take some of my code for this, then please do. The code is used in a GPL2 licensed project hosted on Google Code:

http://code.google.com/p/accountclient/source/browse/#svn/trunk/RegnskapClient/src/no/knubo/accounting/client/validation

It uses the client/ui as well.